# Where are lifecycle callbacks defined?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element, native-web-component

I'm learning about [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks), and I see that in the class definition we can use these methods, the lifecycle callbacks. But I'm a bit confused about how they work. The reason I'm confused is because they're methods, with a particular name, similar to `constructor`, but in difference to `constructor`, they're not defined by the standard. So, where, and how are they defined, in order to be connected with the DOM?

I checked the `HTMLElement`'s prototype, from which custom elements inherit, but it doesn't contain any methods such as `connectedCallback`, `adoptedCallback`, etc. I think they must work something like keywords do, but I'm not sure.

I've read somewhere mentioning web hooks, but didn't understand that. To me, they seem like they have the same functionality to events. So, why don't we use events instead?

Comment: They are just methods that will be called by the browser at the appropriate time if they exist.

Comment: @FelixKling Is that like events?

Comment: Unlike events, they don't propagate. They're just method calls.

Comment: They are (default) **methods and callbacks**. This diagram will help: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman okay, but how are they defined? Through some special syntax?

Comment: The same way push is defined on array

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't think is the same thing, cuz with push we only define the arguments, whereas in this case, we define the body of the function itself.

Comment: "*they're not defined by the standard. So, where, and how are they defined?*" - They are defined by the user as methods on the `class` that implements the custom element. The standard only describes when the browser will call them (if they exist). That's the whole point: they're callbacks.

Comment: default ``HTMLElement`` also has ``constructor``, that is why you don't have to use a ``constructor`` in your own ``class`` when all you have there is ``super()``

Comment: @Bergi exactly that's the part that I want to know: how does the browser know when to call them?

Comment: @jurgen_gjoncari As I wrote, the standard defines when to call them, via [enqueueing a custom element callback reaction](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#enqueue-a-custom-element-callback-reaction)

Answer (score 0):

These callbacks are set at the step 14.4.1 of the [`CustomElementRegistry#define()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#dom-customelementregistry-define) method algorithm:

> 3. Let lifecycleCallbacks be a map with the keys "connectedCallback", "disconnectedCallback", "adoptedCallback", and "attributeChangedCallback", each of which belongs to an entry whose value is null.
> 4. For each of the keys callbackName in lifecycleCallbacks, in the order listed in the previous step:
>
>    1. Let callbackValue be ? Get(prototype, callbackName).
>    2. If callbackValue is not undefined, then set the value of the entry in lifecycleCallbacks with key callbackName to the result of converting callbackValue to the Web IDL Function callback type. Rethrow any exceptions from the conversion.